# Receive data from php using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a function, where if a user selects a value from a drop down list, then this calls an AJAX function, which then should get me a list of Names and their email addresses

```
$.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'get_distusers.php',
                data:'dist_id='+dist_id+'&study_id='+study_id,
                success: function(data){

                    $('#dist_list2').html(data);
                    $('#dist_list').val(data);

                },
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert("There was an error."+textStatus+" - " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    }
            });
```

Then the other page has this to send back the list of names and emails

```
unset($contact);
if ($count_du>0) {
    while($row_du = mysqli_fetch_array($result_du)) {
        if(!empty($contacts)) 
            $contacts.="<br>, ";

            $contact['name']=$row_du[0];
            $contact['email']=$row_du[1];
    }
}

$contacts[]=$contact;
//$contacts=array($contact_email,$contact_name);

//echo $sql_patrand;
echo json_encode($contacts);
```

However, when I try to retrieve the contact list, I either get the word object or nothing.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `data` is a JSON object, not HTML.  You can't directly output it to the page like that, you'd need to extract the data you want from the object and put that data in the page elements.

Comment: I did this, but now when I try to parse the json var json_obj = 
    $.parseJSON(data);//parse JSON - I get an error message "SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"" , but the log shows me that the output looks like [{name: ["Jon Doe"],Email:["jonedoe@email.com"]}]

Comment: Sounds like `data` is an object, not a string.  In which case you don't have to parse it, it's already in the format you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have return `echo json_encode($contacts);` json format from the your php code, but your ajax not understand json format because you have not set `dataType: 'json'` param, Please check the below mention code, it will defiantly helpful, any query comment inside answer....

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'get_distusers.php',
    data:'dist_id='+dist_id+'&study_id='+study_id,
    dataType: 'json', //NOTE:Your missing point - update first
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); //Print your data, so it will help you to how manage
        $('#dist_list2').html(data);
        $('#dist_list').val(data);

    },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("There was an error."+textStatus+" - " + XMLHttpRequest.status);
        }
});
```